# Mapbox custom style for line join

Tags: android, mapbox

I want to customize line join style as in the picture below:
[image]
How can I do it?
My source code:

```
val lineString = LineString.fromLngLats(tempCoordinateList)

val geoJsonSource = GeoJsonSource(DASHED_LINE_SOURCE_ID, Feature.fromGeometry(lineString))

mapboxMap?.addSource(geoJsonSource)

val lineLayer = LineLayer(DASHED_LINE_LAYER_ID, DASHED_LINE_SOURCE_ID).apply {
        setProperties(
                PropertyFactory.lineDasharray(arrayOf(2f, 1f)),
                PropertyFactory.lineCap(Property.LINE_CAP_SQUARE),
                PropertyFactory.lineJoin(Property.LINE_JOIN_ROUND),
                PropertyFactory.lineWidth(3f),
                PropertyFactory.lineColor(Color.parseColor("#e55e5e")))
    }

mapboxMap?.addLayer(lineLayer)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a solution to how to achieve this with standard LineLayer's properties. Therefore, I decided to add these points in a separate layer with markers.

```
val markerCoordinates = arrayListOf<Feature>()
tempCoordinateList
        .forEach {
            val feature = Feature.fromGeometry(
                    Point.fromLngLat(it.longitude, it.latitude))
            markerCoordinates.add(feature)
        }

val geoJsonSource = GeoJsonSource(MARKER_POINTS_SOURCE_ID, FeatureCollection.fromFeatures(markerCoordinates))
mapboxMap?.addSource(geoJsonSource)

mapboxMap?.addImage(MARKER_POINTS_IMAGE_ID, pointIcon)

val markers = SymbolLayer(MARKER_POINTS_LAYER_ID, MARKER_POINTS_SOURCE_ID)
        .withProperties(PropertyFactory.iconImage(MARKER_POINTS_IMAGE_ID))
mapboxMap?.addLayer(markers)
```